# jQuery plugin, imagesLoaded() 'loading .gif'

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Evening!

Currently I'm using imagesLoaded() plugin, and I have a 'loading.gif' image that displays when ajax calls are being made, however, when the imagesLoaded() function is  working its magic on the images, there is no 'loading.gif' which obviously means it's not using ajax. But this looks a bit decieving to the page, because the loading sign is gone, but the page still isn't fully loaded.

I guess I'm asking how can I make the loading.gif appear while imagesLoaded() is working?

http://newgameplus.nikuai.net/TEST/
(Second search bar if you want to see what I mean.)

```
///////This is the code I used to make a loading bar when ajax is called. 
$("#spinner").bind("ajaxSend", function() {
    $(this).show();
}).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
    $(this).hide();
}).bind("ajaxError", function() {
    $(this).hide();
});

///////Where the plugin is called:
var $items = $( items.join('') );
$items.imagesLoaded(function(){
$container
.append( $items ).masonry( 'appended', $items, true );
});
}
```

Comment: Put your code and related markup and if necessary CSS *within the question*. It's just the friendly thing to do when you're asking for help, to isolate the part that's the problem. If you can't, then work on making a http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate.

Comment: Sorry, updated to reflect your suggestion.